# How to get/use Counter Values in Python for word frequency of a text file

Tags: python, counter, word-frequency

I'm new to Python and facing some problems with my codes for counting words in a text file and doing some other stuffs with them. Here's what I'm trying to do:

I want to print the frequency of the exact word I give as input/arguments in the function from the Counter/Dictionary that was created from a text file. And I want to sum all the values of the word frequencies. For example, if "apple", 2 and "banana", 5 , then I want to get the value 7. Also, when dumping into pickle, I get an error

So far, I tried this and got a lot of error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import os
import pickle
from collections import Counter

os.chdir("E:/")


def wfrequencies(word, text):
    f1 = open('words.txt', 'r')
    # Dictionary to find Unique words and their frequency
    message1 = f1.read()

    # count all word frequencies
    c = Counter(message1.split()).items()
    print(c)

    #count the total number of words
    f = sum(c.values())
    print(f)

    # only print the value of the given word argument. This case 'or' as the argument
    p_word_count = word

    #Return the value of dictionary for the passed argument
    c["p_word_count"]

#dump value of dictionary item in pickle file
    pickle.dump(c, open("my_out.dat", "wb"))
```

And this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
dict_items([('EGG-PLANTS', 1), ('IN', 1), ('THE', 1), ('OVEN', 1), ('(Melanzane', 1), ('al', 1), ('forno)', 1), ('Skin', 1), ('five', 1), ('or', 2), ('six', 1), ('egg-plants,', 1), ('cut', 1), ('them', 2), ('in', 4), ('round', 1), ('slices', 2), ('and', 6), ('salt', 1), ('so', 1), ('that', 2), ('they', 2), ('throw', 1), ('out', 1), ('the', 6), ('water', 1), ('contain.', 1), ('After', 1), ('a', 5), ('few', 1), ('hours', 1), ('dip', 1), ('flour', 1), ('frying', 1), ('oil.', 1), ('Take', 1), ('fireproof', 1), ('vase', 2), ('baking', 1), ('tin', 1), ('place', 1), ('layers,', 1), ('with', 4), ('grated', 2), ('cheese', 2), ('between', 1), ('each', 1), ('layer,', 1), ('abundantly', 1), ('seasoned', 1), ('tomato', 2), ('sauce', 1), ('(No.', 1), ('12).', 1), ('Beat', 1), ('one', 1), ('egg', 2), ('pinch', 1), ('of', 5), ('salt,', 1), ('tablespoonful', 1), ('sauce,', 1), ('teaspoonful', 1), ('two', 1), ('crumbs', 1), ('bread,', 1), ('cover', 1), ('upper', 1), ('layer', 1), ('this', 1), ('sauce.', 1), ('Put', 1), ('oven', 1), ('when', 1), ('is', 1), ('coagulated,', 1), ('serve', 1), ('hot.', 1)])

File "C:/Users/mn-ra/PycharmProjects/untitled/NLP.py", line 49, in <module>
wfrequencies("or", "recipe_Ital_102")

File "C:/Users/mn-ra/PycharmProjects/untitled/NLP.py", line 19, in wfrequencies
f = sum(c.values())
AttributeError: 'dict_items' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Comment: Can you post your error?

Answer (score 0):

I think `p_word_count = word` is useless, and `c["p_word_count"]` is the source of the error, try `c[p_word_count]` (or `c[word]`).

And post the error please.

EDIT: From the error, a `Counter` does not have a "values()" method, you need to iterate over the (word, freq) tupes.

Comment: Error posted now. Sorry for not putting earlier.

Comment: Changed my answer